# Entering an infinite loop when entering an invalid time unit

Tags: c

In this code the user inters inputs and accordingly it calculates the radioactive output.

The code works perfectly fine until I ask the user to enter a time unit, whether he enters a correct char (h, d, y) or an incorrect char, the code prints out the error code and ask for time unit again, and it never ends!
starting from the last if statement

if (timeUnit !='h' || timeUnit !='H' || timeUnit !='d' || timeUnit !='D' || timeUnit !='y' || timeUnit !='Y')

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define year 365.25;            //Defining year
#define day 24.0                //Defining day


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
double maxA0 = 1e6;
double A0;                  //initial activity
double t;                   //time elapsed since the initial activity measured
double oldt;                //will set the value of t = oldt before conversion.
char timeUnit;              //Type of time (hours, day or year)
double T;                   //half-life
int isotope;                //Type of isotope
double radioActive;         //Radio Active final result

printf("\nAvailable isotopes:\n");
printf("[1] Actinium 227    (Ac-227)\n");
printf("[2] Barium 140      (Ba-140)\n");
printf("Cesium 134          (Cs-134)\n");
printf("Iodine 132          (I-132)\n");

printf("\nEnter the isotope index (1-4)\n");            //Promoting user to enter index for isotope type
scanf("%d", &isotope);


if (isotope > 4 || isotope < 1) {
    do {
        printf("ERROR: That is not a valid index.\n");
        printf("\nEnter the isotope index (1-4)\n");
        scanf("%d", &isotope);
    }
    while (isotope > 4 || isotope < 1);
}


    switch(isotope)
{                                       //Switch to assign T value according to isotope type
    case 1:
        T = 21.77 * year;
        break;
    case 2:
        T = 12.8;
        break;
    case 3:
        T = 2.06 * year;
        break;
    case 4:
        T = 2.26 / day;
        break;

}

printf("\nEnter the initial activity A0 in microCi."); //Promoting user to input initial activity value
scanf("%lf", &A0);


if (A0 < 0 || A0 > maxA0) {
    do {
        printf("ERROR: That is not a valid initial activity level. \n");
        printf("\nEnter the initial activity A0 in microCi.");
        scanf("%lf", &A0);
    }
    while (A0 < 0 || A0 > maxA0);
}


printf("\nEnter the decay time t:\n");                  //promoting user to enter time
scanf("%lf", &t);


if (t < 0) {
    do {
        printf("ERROR: Negative or zero time is not valid.\n");
        printf("\nEnter the decay time t:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &t);
    }
    while (A0 < 0 || A0 > maxA0);
}

oldt = t;                                               //origina t input from user to appear in final equation (t timeUnit)


printf("\nEnter the time unit (h/d/y)\n");              // Promoting user to input type of time
scanf("  %c", &timeUnit );

//checking if time type entered is either hours, days or years.

if (timeUnit !='h' || timeUnit !='H' || timeUnit !='d' || timeUnit !='D' || timeUnit !='y' || timeUnit !='Y') {

    do {
        printf("ERROR: That is not a valid time unit.\n");
        printf("\nEnter the time unit (h/d/y)\n");
        scanf("  %c", &timeUnit );
    }
    while (timeUnit !='h' || timeUnit !='H' || timeUnit !='d' || timeUnit !='D' || timeUnit !='y' || timeUnit !='Y');
}

else if (timeUnit =='h' || timeUnit =='H' || timeUnit =='d' || timeUnit =='D' || timeUnit =='y' || timeUnit =='Y')
{
    if (timeUnit == 'h' || timeUnit == 'H')             //converting hours to days
        t = t / day;
    else if (timeUnit == 'y' || timeUnit == 'Y')        //converting years to days
        t = t * year;
}

radioActive = (double) (A0 * exp(-0.693*t/T));                     //radio active equation

printf("\nA(%.1lf %c) %.4e uCi\n", oldt,timeUnit,radioActive);      //desired output

return 0;
```

}

Comment: "...and ask for time unit again, and it never ends!" That is because code never reads the offending input.  It remains in `stdin` until read.  Research `fgets()` for reading user input instead of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'or' operators means that the `if` statement will be entered if any of those conditions are not met. Since it is not possible to meet all of those conditions at once, it will be entered every time. Use 'and' operators.

```
if (timeUnit !='h' && timeUnit !='H' && timeUnit !='d' && timeUnit !='D' && timeUnit !='y' && timeUnit !='Y')
```